# How to make the FilmRoll carousel in html Pulgin is [https://github.com/straydogstudio/film_roll/tree/master/js]

Tags: jquery, html, carousel

I want the image to scroll like the filmroll. and also wanted to include the prev and nxt button.

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="lightbox2/lightbox2-master/dist/css/lightbox.css" title="style">
    <script src="C:\Users\hp-pc\Desktop\M1 cinemas\film_roll-master\film_roll-master\js\jquery.film_roll.js"></script>

    <script src="C:\Users\hp-pc\Desktop\M1 cinemas\film_roll-master\film_roll-master\js

    \jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>

    <script>

     $(function() {
          fr = new FilmRoll({
            container: '#film_roll',
            height:500,
            animation: 1000,
            interval: 10000,
            prev: '#film_roll_prev',
            next: '#film_roll_next'
          });
        });

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="film_roll">
<div><a href='#'><img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437"></a></div>
<div><a href='#'><img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-4r8uIjK6EVM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/hmkw4cD96mA/s100-c-k-no/photo.jpg"></a></div>
<div><a href='#'><img src="http://www.123inkt.nl/image/Riso_S-4263E_inktcartridge_helderrood_origineel_S-4263E_087016_small.jpg"></a></div>
</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**And also how to include the previous and next button?**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Gsi6CKxRaa--> it is the jfiddle..

Comment: srcipt [https://github.com/straydogstudio/film_roll/blob/master/js/jquery.film_roll.js]

Comment: please edit your question to add all the relevant information